# Markovian chains with Redis

Tags: redis, markov-chains

For self-education purposes, I want to implement a Markov chain generator, using as much Redis, and as little application-level logic as possible.

Let's say I want to build a word generator, based on frequency table with history depth N (say, 2).

As a not very interesting example, for dictionary of two words `bar` and `baz`, the frequency table is as follows ("." is terminator, numbers are weights):

```
. . -> b x2
. b -> a x2
b a -> r x1
b a -> z x1
a r -> . x1
a z -> . x1
```

When I generate the word, I start with history of two terminators `. .`

There is only one possible outcome for the first two letters, `b a`.

Third letter may be either `r` or `z`, with equal probabilities, since their weights are equal.

Fourth letter is always a terminator.

(Things would be more interesting with longer words in dictionary.)

Anyway, how to do this with Redis elegantly?

Redis sets have `SRANDMEMBER`, but do not have weights.

Redis sorted sets have weights, but do not have random member retrieval.

Redis lists allow to represent weights as entry copies, but how to make set intersections with them?

Looks like application code is doomed to do some data processing...

Comment: "Redis sorted sets have weights, but do not have random member retrieval." ... This is trivial to implement. Simply get the length of a sorted set using `ZCARD key` then choose a random number between 0 and the length of the sorted set, and finally fetch the random member using `ZRANGE key rand_num rand_num`.

Comment: @CarlZulauf: Does the approach you describe take the weight into account when doing the random retrieval? Doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish a weighted random selection with a redis sorted set, by assigning each member a score between zero and one, according to the *cumulative* probability of the members of the set considered thus far, *including* the current member.
The ordering you use is irrelevant; you may choose any order which is convenient for you.  The random selection is then accomplished by generating a random floating point number **r** uniformly distributed between zero and one, and calling

> ZRANGEBYSCORE zset **r** 1 LIMIT 0 1,

which will return the first element with a score greater than or equal to **r**.
A little bit of reasoning should convince you that the probability of choosing a member is thus weighted correctly.

Unfortunately, the fact that the scores assigned to the elements needs to be proportional to the *cumulative* probability would seem to make it difficult to use the sorted set union or intersection operations in a way which would preserve the significance of the scores for random selection of elements.  That part *would* seem to require some significant application logic.